# How can I enable the logging in smart contract?

Tags: hardhat

I am writing smart contract code using hardhat but not able to see the console logs in production/testnet deployment. I am using hardhat console.sol library Is it only usable for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [console.sol](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/master/packages/hardhat-core/console.sol) on Github,you will notice that it has an address hardcoded (0x000000000000000000636F6e736F6c652e6c6f67) where it will send the logged data.
That hardcoded address seems to belong to a local hardhat blockchain smart contract that emits events with the information and hardhat listens to them and shows them in the javascript console.

This console.log utility is intended to be used only locally while developing, using the local hardhat blockchain.

I suggest using regular events to emit what you need from your contract. Events are cheap and useful.